canonical involution in group algebras
Let $G$ be a finite group. If $K$ has involution $-:K \to K$, the canonical involution $*:KG \to KG$ is defined as $$(\sum_ga_gg)^*=\sum_g\bar{a}_gg^{-1}.$$


Question: When is each centrally primitive idempotent $e_i$ of $(KG,*)$ self-adjoint?


The statement is true when $(K,\bar{})$ is a real closed field with trivial conjugation or the field of complex numbers with complex conjugate involution. I show it as follows:

Note that $KG=A_1 \times \cdots \times A_r$, where each $A_i=KGe_i$ is a simple component of $KG$. Since this decomposition is unique, $A_i^*=A_j$. If I prove that $A_i$ is involution invariant (i.e. $A_i^*=A_i$), then I am done.
Define $T(a)=tr(l_a)$, where $l_a \in \text{End}_K(KG)$ is the left multiplication map by $a$ ($l_a(x)=ax$). Computation shows that $T(a)=|G|a_{1_G}$. Consequently $$t(a,b)=T(ab^*)=|G|(ab^*)_{1_G}=|G|\sum_{g \in G}a_g\bar{b}_g.$$
The form $t$ is nondegenerate when $(K,\bar{})$ is a real closed field with trivial conjugation or the field of complex numbers with complex conjugate involution.
We know that $A_iA_j=0$ for $i\ne j$. If $A_i \ne A_i^*$, there would exist nonzero $a \in A_i$ such that $t(a,a)=T(aa^*)=0$, which would cantradict the nondegenerecy of $t$. Therefore, $A_i=A_i^*$, and so $e_i=e_i^*$.

Is this proof correct?
How can we generalize it to other fields?
To which field we can generalize this argument?

Not a full answer, but some thoughts. For reference, let's call Case 1: $K$ real closed, $\bar{}$ trivial; Case 2: $K = \mathbb C$, $\bar{}=$complex conjugation. Note that the form $t(a,b)$ is bilinear in case 1 but sesquilinear in case 2.
In either case, $t$ being nondegenerate means "$t(a,x)=0$ for all $x \implies a=0$". The crux of the matter is that in either case, the argument uses a much stronger condition than this: It uses that the form is anisotropic, i.e. $t(a,a)=0 \implies a=0$.
Note that "most" forms, even if nondegenerate, are isotropic. The form $t(\cdot, \cdot)$ you define here, w.r.t. the basis given by the elements of $G$, is represented by the easiest symmetric / hermitian matrix, namely $Id_{|G|}$. This form is always nondegenerate; it happens to be anisotropic in the two cases considered, but that is something that feels rather specific to these cases. Let's consider two examples where the result is false but can be fixed by a better choice of the involution; at the end there is a third example where no such fix is possible. In all examples, I take $G=$ cyclic group of order $4$ with elements $\{e, g, g^2, g^3=g^{-1}\}$, which is kind of the easiest non-trivial cases.
Example 1: $K= \mathbb C$, $\bar{}=$ identity (not complex conjugation). Then $KG \simeq \mathbb C \times \mathbb C \times \mathbb C \times \mathbb C$ where $g$ operates via $1, i, -1, -i$ on the four factors, respectively. But $\ast$ flips the factors on which it operates via $i$ and $-i$ with each other. Concretely, e.g. $\ast(\frac12(1+ig-g^2-ig^3))=\frac12(1-ig-g^2+ig^3)$ and these are two different centrally primitive idempotents.
(Note that letting $\bar{}$ = complex conjugation instead of the identity would "repair" this. The hermitian form represented by $Id_{|G|}$ is anisotropic, but the $\mathbb C$-bilinear form, which comes into play if $\bar{}=id$, is not.)
Example 2: $K= \mathbb Q(\zeta_8) = \mathbb Q(i, \sqrt2)$. We have $Gal(K|\mathbb Q) \simeq \mathbb Z/2 \times \mathbb Z/2$ where one pair of generators is given by $\sigma =$ complex conjugation and $\tau(\sqrt2)=-\sqrt2$, $\tau(i)=i$, respectively. Choose $\bar{}=\tau$. Again $KG$ is just four copies of $K$, with $g$ acting via $1,i,-1,-i$ as before, and because everything of interest (e.g. the same idempotents as in example 1) is defined over $\mathbb Q(i)$ i.e. gets fixed by $\tau$, the example works just as before, the only difference being that now $t(\cdot, \cdot)$ is a ($\tau$-) sesquilinear form, still nondegenerate but isotropic. (I.e. here, twisting by $\tau$ did not help. One "should have" twisted by the complex conjugation.)

I'm not saying that anisotropy of the form is necessary for the conclusion you want to hold. But the examples show that non-degeneracy is not sufficient in general.
The moral of both examples, in fact, might be that "the right" field involution that "belongs to" inversion of the group elements "is" complex conjugation (because this is true for roots of unity, and cyclic groups operate via such). In fact you can generalize your two cases to the following, which also "fixes" both examples:
Proposition: Let $K$ be a field which has an embedding $\iota: K \hookrightarrow \mathbb C$ such that $\iota(K)$ is stable under complex conjugation. Then if $\bar{}$ is (the pullback along $\iota$ of) the restriction of complex conjugation to $K$, every centrally primitive idempotent of $KG$ is self-adjoint w.r.t. $*$.
But there are still many examples where this does not work:
Example 3: Let $K=\mathbb Q_p$ (field of $p$-adic numbers) where $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ (these contain square roots of $-1$). Let $G$ be the cyclic group of order $4$. Then everything works like in Example 1, and now there is no "fix" to that by choosing anything else than $\bar{} = id$, because $\mathbb Q_p$ has no field automorphisms except the identity. (With axiom of choice, $\mathbb Q_p$ has embeddings into $\mathbb C$, but the fact that $\mathbb Q_p$ has no nontrivial field automorphisms shows that none of those (besides them being "impossible to write down explicitly") would be stable under complex conjugation.)

Thank you. I have found the following in the book Orthogonal, Symplectic and Unitary Representation of Finite Groups by Riehm: Let $A$ be a simple direct summand of $KG$, and $\rho : G \to GL_K(V )$ a linear K-representation of $G$ which is $A$-isotypic ($AV = V $). $A^*=A$, where * is the canonical $(K,\bar{})$-involution on $KG$ if and only if there is a nonsingular sesquilinear form $h: V \times V \to (K,\bar{})$ which is $G$-invariant.

Now, for arbitrary $KG$ module $V$ (not necessarily $A$-isotypic), $(V, h)$ is anisotropic if and only if $V$ has no non-trivial totally isotropic subspace, if and only if
every subspace of $V$ is non-singular.

Nice, that's a more precise version, but also it confirms and generalizes what I'm saying. So for the statement to hold we need (much more, but e.g.) that for any $1$-dimensional $K$-representation $\chi$ of $G$, each element $g\in G$ has to act via a scalar $s:=\chi(g)$ such that $\bar{s} = s^{-1}$ (so that $(v,w)\stackrel{!}=(sv, sw) = s\bar{s}\cdot (v,w)$) . But by finiteness of $G$ also $s$ is a root of unity, meaning that for any embedding $K \hookrightarrow \mathbb C$, $s^{-1} =$ complex conjugate of $s$.

Your proof is correct about every 3 steps.
About decomposition into Simple Components, You correctly decomposed the group algebra into simple components.
And, For Invariance of Simple Components, You showed that if a simple component is not invariant under the involution, it would lead to a contradiction with the nondegeneracy of the trace form.
Finally, proving the Nondegeneracy of trace Form, You used the specific properties of the given fields to establish the nondegeneracy of the trace form.
To generalize this argument to other fields, we need to find conditions under which the trace form remains nondegenerate.
One possible generalization is to consider separable field extensions. If $K$ is a separable field extension of a field $F$, then the trace form on $KG$ is nondegenerate iff the trace form on $FG$ is nondegenerate. This allows us to reduce the problem to the base field $F$.

Do you have a reference that shows your claim? If $K$ is a field extension of $F$, what is the restriction of involution to $F$?
